# Submit Page Information using Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, submit-button

I have a react-app with individual components. Here is a snippet of that code.

```
const form = (props) => {
  <Paper className={classes.root}>
    <TextInput name="TextOne" minimum="0" maximum="100" value="50" />
  </Paper>

  <Paper className={classes.root}>
    <Slider name="slider_one" minimum="0" maximum="50" val="10"/>
  <Paper/>
  <SubmitButton/>
};
export default Form

}
```

with each component defined in its own file. Currently the page renders properly but I want a button to push all the data to an external API created with Django. I have confirmed the props update properly when manipulating the slider and text input.

Right now the button renders, but does nothing.

This react app was created using hooks, but most resources online use class components so it's hard to follow. There are many more components but adding them here would be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle values by state and send them to the API.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const form = (props) => {
  const [textOne, updateTextOne] = useState(50)
  const [slider_one, updateSlider_one] = useState(10)
  const submit = ()=>{
    APICall({textOne, slider_one})
  }
  return(
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <TextInput onChange={e =>{updateTextOne(e.target.val)}} name="TextOne" minimum="0" maximum="100" value={textOne} />
    </Paper>

    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Slider onChange={e =>{updateTextOne(e.target.val)}} name="slider_one" minimum="0" maximum="50" val={slider_one} />
    <Paper/>
      <SubmitButton onSubmit={ submit } /> // or pass values down to button in order to send it to server values={{slider_one, textOne}}
    </Paper>
  )
}
export default Form
```

Comment: Thanks. Where would I declare the URL of the API. Also many of these components are reusable. Does that complicate things?

Comment: It depends on how are you handling your API calls if you are using fetch or a js framework for it.